# non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

Don't want any code, just want some sort of guidance. Would like to keep my academic integrity in tact ;)

I keep getting that annoying error. I need to call the toString method for each Room instance. Any suggestions? I would prefer an answer within 2 hours if at all possible.

```
public class Hotel
{
    //constant
    public static final int NUM_ROOMS = 20;

    //variables
    public Room[] theRoom;
    public String name;
    public int totalDays;
    public double totalRate;
    public int singleCount;
    public int doubleCount;
    public int roomsRented;
    public int NOT_FOUND;

    public Hotel(String newName) {
        name = newName;
        Room[] Rooms = new Room[NUM_ROOMS];
    }

    public double getTotalRentalSales() {
        return totalRate + roomsRented;
    }

    public double getAvgDays() {
        return roomsRented/totalDays;
    }

    public double getAvgRate() {
        return totalRate/roomsRented;
    }

    public int getSingleCount() {
        return singleCount;
    }

    public int getDoubleCount() {
        return doubleCount;
    }

    public String printRentalList() {
        System.out.println("Room Information: " + Room.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: 1+ for not asking for the code solution. This is the right attitude!

Comment: But one thing -- please leave mention of "deadlines" and similar out of your question. Please note that 1) you're asking for help from volunteers and so really shouldn't be trying to rush or pressure them, and 2) the speed with which your question gets a good answer is most often directly related to the quality of the question. To whit: Does it have the information needed to be answered and is it easy to read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't try to call `toString()` on a Room class but rather on a Room *object*. In that method, loop through the array of rooms with a for loop and print the String returned by calling `toString()` for each Room object held in the array since this is what it looks like your method should do.

For example

```
System.out.println("All Foos held here include: ");

// using a "for-each" loop, assuming an array called fooArray that holds Foo objects
for (Foo foo: fooArray) {
   System.out.println(foo);
}
```

You will obviously have to change the types and variable names for your code.

Edit 2: although you will have to use a standard for loop, not a for-each loop, since you won't be looping through the entire array, but rather will quit when roomsRented count is reached.

```
System.out.println("All Foos held here include: ");

// using standard for loop, assuming an array called fooArray that holds Foo objects
for (int i = 0; i < someMaxNumber; i++) {
   System.out.println(fooArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for awesome username. :D  (But seriously, for the answer.)

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I'm still working on it lol....obviously i'm newer at this lol. Thanks for your time and patience =D

Comment: @user1848879: you're welcome. Keep trying, keep experimenting.

Comment: Btw i'll be sure to leave out deadlines next time =)

This is what I have so far:

Answer (score 1):

As error is already states, do not call instance method in static context.

Room is a class, not an object. toString is a instance method. So Room.toString() in this case  compiler looks for a static method toString. But toString is an instance method so it is causing an issue.

Always remember instance methods are called with the object of the class, not with class itself.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Od Eels
*sigh* I cannot get my code to post right....

I keep getting a " cannot find symbol" in the "System.out.println(Room[i]);" line of my code. (I've decided to abandon the toString method so i could at least complete the code lol. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably doing is calling `toString()` on the class Room, not an instance of it. For example, instead of writing:

```
Room.toString()
```

write:

```
Room r = new Room()
r.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code, you can compile toString with a static variable without a new object, it just throw exception at run time

```
demo>cat Test.java 
class Water {
  public String toString() {return "whatever";}
}

public class Test { 
  static Water water;
  public static void main(String...args) {
    System.out.println(water.toString());
  }
}

demo>javac Test.java 
demo>java Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Comment: An answer has been already accepted a looong time ago. Does yours add antything valuable to the OP? Think that before re-answering such an old question.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

In this line when you are writing arrays a dropdown menu will appear, there you will see the default package or the `java.util` package. You need to select the `java.util` package and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling classname.method(), it means that you are calling a static method. We use the classname inorder to call the static methods.

Here class is : Room

Method is : toString()

toString() is not a static method to be called with class name.

toString() is the method of the Object class.

So you should use room.toString() where 'room' is the object of the Room class